# How to make a query to filter with a pivot table & another table in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5

Sorry for the title I really don't know what to call it.

I am building a illustration website with albums.
A illustration can be uploaded to a album.

In the photos table I have a processed table in it.
This way I can check if the illustration was processed or not, if yes then it can be searchable if not then the user must edit the processed illustration or illustrations.

I can select the photos in the specific album but I don't know how to filter with the processed illustration belonging to the viewing album.

Also I have  a seperate table album_photos table.
The relation of a album and a photo is hasMany and belongsToMany.

This way I select all the photos but not filtered with processed or not.

```
$photos = Photo::whereIn('id', $album -> album_photos() -> pluck('photo_id'))->get();
```

And this way I select all the processed photos of the corresponding user.

```
$photosNotProcessed = Photo::where('user_id', Auth::user() -> id)->whereNull('processed')->get();
```

Now I want to select the photos in the viewing album that is not been processed.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your modal along with the relations so we can help you to write the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found you have 3 table photo, album and a table that call processed!
photo and album have many to many relation and photo with processed table has a relation too, if you want select processed photos that belog to a album, because of that you can add a where in you photo table:

```
  Photo::where('user_id', Auth::user() -> id)->whereNull('processed')->whereIn('id', $album -> album_photos()) -> pluck('photo_id'))->get();;
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply. I found a way. Your way is also nice.
I have now a function in the modal. Little cleaner

Comment: This is the code that I used. I don't know it works haha
    public function processed()
    {
        return $this->photos->where('processed',1)->all();
    }